# Reading data from SalesForce and storing UserInformation to Salesforce from Web 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java

We have a new module being developed using SDL Web 8.5 DXA R2. We would be required to integrate our CMS to communicate with a Salesforce module via a Middleware. However, I am not aware of what should be the best approach for such implementations.

It is an open question, and I would like to know some best practice solutions that could be used for my use case.

Any information regarding what all SalesForce APIs to use and also, how best to define our schemas, so that, we can display user information from Salesforce, would be much appreciated.

Apologies for such a vague problem statement. However, if anyone of you has already done any such implementations, and could share some insights, would be of great help to us.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

SDL has a Salesforce connector (commercial offering) which could solve your challenge. It consists of an ECL connector to easily add Salesforce forms onto pages, but also front end microservice and Audience Manager integration plus ADF cartridge to expose Salesforce lead/user information into the session data to easily display user details within a web page.

Please let me know if you would like to learn more about it.

Comment: Yes I would like to learn more. Is it part of the SDL Web 8.5 offering?

Comment: this may help: https://www.sdl.com/software-and-services/integrations/

Answer (score 0):

It's different possible way to achieve this, One of our previous implementations contact us form integrated with SalesForce. We exposed a web service to talk between contact us form and sales force.

Maybe in the same approach, you can expose a scheduled windows service to talk to the SalesForce and SDL Web using core service.

It's just my idea wait for others feedback too.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

ECL has been the preferred way of doing such things but its costly (to build or to buy), buying could be the fastest way of moving forward however Velu's idea is worth giving a try.